# Gathering object (MICE output for five imputed datasets)?

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, r-mice

I am using MICE to impute data in a multilevel model. I then use the "with()" function in MICE to do multilevel analyses with lmer(). This first dataset looks at total crime. Then I do another set of analyses looking at crime type, so the violent and property crime are gathered. Originally, for this second dataset, I thought to gather property and violent crime prior to imputation and then impute predictors, but this is taking FOREVER (over 20 hours). Is there a way to gather the MICE output (mice.crime below), so that I can then model violent and property crime values?

Thanks much!

Here's a reproducible example, essentially, I just want to gather violent and property crime:

```
library(mice)
df.1 <- data.frame(place_id = as.integer(seq (1:n)),
property_crime = as.numeric(sample(c(20:90), n, rep = TRUE)),
violent_crime = as.numeric(sample(c(20:90), n, rep = TRUE)),
med_income = sample(c(20:90), n, rep = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(crime_total = property_crime + violent_crime)

df <- apply(subset(df.1,select=-c(place_id, property_crime, violent_crime, crime_total)), 2, function(x)
     {x[sample(c(1:n),floor(n/10))]<-NA; x}) 
df.1 <- df.1%>%select(-(med_income))
df <- cbind(df.1, df)

impmethod.1 <- character(ncol(df))
names(impmethod.1) <- colnames(df)
impmethod.1[c("med_income")] <- "2l.lmer" 
impmethod.1[c("place_id", "property_crime", "violent_crime", "crime_total")] <- ""
impmethod.1

pm <- make.predictorMatrix(df)
pm["place_id",] <- -c(0,0,0,0,2)
pm["property_crime",] <- -c(-2,0,0,0,2)
pm["violent_crime",] <- -c(-2,0,0,0,2)
pm["crime_total",] <- -c(-2,0,0,0,2)
pm["med_income",] <- -c(-2,0,0,0,0)

mice.crime <- mice(df, m=5, predictorMatrix = pm,
                    method=impmethod.1, maxit=10, printFlag = FALSE, seed=1874)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm following up on my question here with an answer...in hopes that I can anyone here implementing the MICE package a lot of time and frustration. The MICE package is amazing. It is well thought out and versatile. And the "with()" function--where one can easily incorporate the five separate datasets through multiple or multilevel regression--is emblematic of that. However, if you plan on then using sjPlot (another amazing, incredibly well thought out package) to plot effect sizes, or if you're wanting to cross-validate your findings; I would stop with MICE after imputation and switch to the sjMisc package (another package by Daniel Ludecke) which has a "merge_imputations()" function that will take the imputed vectors and merge them with your initial dataset. More on the cogs of that here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjmisc/versions/2.8.4/topics/merge_imputations (this is actually one of the only Rdocumentations I have found where there IS a useful example). Thus, you now have one dataset with your imputed values and you can move forward with lme4 (and/or subdivisions for cross-validation) or whatever regressions you are carrying out.

Statistically speaking, I think the "with()" function is better, as it takes the five separate lists of imputed data and merges them with the original dataset as you impute, but practically speaking, if you're looking to plot or cross-validate, you'll end up on a dead-end road. Until someone posts a more sufficient statistical or computational answer to the question, hopefully this will save you going down that road I already did.